# Right pypeline to shoot crowd on chromakey, to add 3d on post

Tags: video, camera, 3d, visual-effects, chromakey

I NEED THIS TYPE OF PRODUCTION+VFX+3D ANIMATION
[VFX+3D](https://youtu.be/Kg8lC7nUyQ4?si=7puo7V30wv6gciSG)

My storyboard of the scene:
[image: Frame 1 - A man on a air baloon attracts a crowd]
[image: Frame 2 - Crowd about 20ppl]
[image: Frame 3 - they go into a air balloon]
[image: Optional frame - look from top]
[image: Frame 5 - look from down to flying baloons with ppl]

If We shoot the crowd on a chromakey from these angles, which option would be easier and faster:

1. To make a full 3D city scene, and put footages into 3d scene?
2. To shoot the real city from exactly the same angles, and just add 3D air balloons into city footage, and put crowd footage into 3D balloon?
3. Just shoot on camera crowd in the city, and imitate camera angle to the sky, to add on post the 3d balloons, with tracking and compositing(masking crowd)
4. ... I dont know

I found this tutorial, but im not sure how to get right results. I just dont know the right pypeline

[Chromakey in Blender](https://youtu.be/RxD6H3ri8RI?si=cJ-N5ZWeqr4EGXYg)

Please share the right pypeline! More about how to shoot and work with chromakey

Btw, i need to understand how to make this type video until 15 march(15 march will video-prod day)

UPD.
Softwares: Blender, C4D, Embergen, FSpy, Material Maker, AE, Davinci Resolve, Photoshop, AI, Audition, Premiere Pro, Final Cut

Our skills:

1. Concept arts
2. 2D/3D motion design - Blender mostly, a bit C4D
3. Rigging and character animation
4. Blender Geo-Nodes - junior
5. VFX - Embergen, AE, Davinci Resolve Fusion
6. Tracking - KeenTools, FSpy, Blender, AE, C4D
7. Compositing - AE, Davinci Resolve
8. Video shooting
9. Film Making
10. Color Correction
11. Editing

I NEED THIS TYPE OF VFX+3D ANIMATION:
[VFX + 3D ANIMATION WITH LARGE CITY BACKGROUND](https://youtu.be/Kg8lC7nUyQ4?si=ezWYrkcmO39eKkNc)
Scenario of video - one blogger on an air balloon(in the city, ground) calls a crowd of people, atract them. They are come to him, listen something and follow him, buy standing on an air balloon. And Balloon starts flying from the city. Next shot is fro the ground looking to the sky, how these people flying on a balloon. Final shot from the sky, air balloon flying to another city.
15 March - day of shooting(production), we will do prod.
So until 15 March i need to get the best way to shoot

And I guess i have enough of skills to make it, i'm just not sure in pypeline